# How do I show the tangent to an elliptic curve over the complex numbers meets the elliptic curve at another point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

If $E(\mathbb{C})$ is an elliptic curve given by $y^2=ax^3+bx+c$ for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{C}$, and $\ell$ is a line tangent to $E(\mathbb{C})$ at some point $p$, then why does $\ell$ meet $E(\mathbb{C})$ at another point that is not $p$? I see that if the tangent line is given by $x=C$ for some constant $C\in \mathbb{C}$, then the line meets $E(\mathbb{C})$ in the point $\mathcal{O}$ at infinity. I also see that since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, substituting the equation $y=\alpha x + \beta$ of $\ell$ into $y^2=ax^3+bx+c$ yields three solutions, but why must the third one be different?

**EDIT:** Of course the tangent at $\mathcal{O}$ meets the curve at only one point, but what about the other points?

Comment: There can be points $p$ such that the tangent line in $p$ meets $E$ only at $p$; these are precisely the $3$-torsion points on $E$. Over $\mathbb C$, there are $9$ of them (including $\mathcal O$).

Comment: I had not considered this, thanks!

Comment: If your point is an inflection point, the tangent line there has contact of order (at least) three; since the curve is cubic, precisely three. Conversely, if the point is not an inflection point, the tangent line meets the curve only doubly there, so must hit somewhere else, too. I strongly recommend doing hand computations here. Try the curve $Y^2=X^3+1$ and its obvious five integral points in the finite plane. There’s nothing like spending a night with an elliptic curve for gaining true intimacy.